# Grab posts by multiple categories

Tags: php, categories, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

So I have the below code that works great:

```
if (isset($meta_field['category'])) {
    $post_data = get_posts_by_category($meta_field['category'], 0,
        $post_limit);
} else {
    $post_data = get_posts_by_category('1', 0, $post_limit);
}

// Extract posts
$posts = $post_data['posts'];
```

Where in the else statement, I'm calling to pull in all posts tagged the `1` category which is working great.

---

Here is what I'd like to achieve - So I'm attempting to pull posts from two different categories in the else statement, but I can't seem to make it work correctly.

Here is my attempt:

```
        if (isset($meta_field['category'])) {
            // Get all post data for that category
            $post_data = get_posts_by_category($meta_field['category'], 0,
                $post_limit);
        } else {
            $args = [
                'posts_per_page' => $post_limit,
                'offset'=> 1,
                'category' => [
                    '9', '3'
                ]
            ];
            $post_data = get_posts($args);
        }
```

I'd like to pull in all posts from my categories tagged 9 and 3, but I'm getting no results back - but when I call get_posts_by_category, I in fact do get results back.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

```
        if (isset($meta_field['category'])) {
            // Get all post data for that category
            $post_data = get_posts_by_category($meta_field['category'], 0,
                $post_limit);
        } else {
            $args = array(
              'numberposts' => $post_limit,
              'offset'=> 1,
              'category' => '9,3',
            );
            $post_data = get_posts($args);
        }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me @Michelle :( - I've updated the post to show what the next calls is dependent which is `$posts = $post_data['posts'];`. - So get_posts_by_category, returns a 'posts' array.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you were using posts_per_page, that should be numberposts. See updated answer. @Dave

Comment: Also @Dave I didn't test $post_data['posts'] but you can see what's in the $post_data array using var_dump($post_data); after the if/else call.